# Android Class marked as never used

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a really easy class (ColorTool.java):

```
import android.graphics.Color;

public class ColorTool {

    public boolean closeMatch (int color1, int color2, int tolerance) {
        if (Math.abs (Color.red (color1) - Color.red (color2)) > tolerance ) return false;
        if (Math.abs (Color.green (color1) - Color.green (color2)) > tolerance ) return false;
        return Math.abs(Color.blue(color1) - Color.blue(color2)) <= tolerance;
    }
}
```

And I'm using it in the Main class:

```
private final ColorTool ct = new ColorTool ();
```

And using it:

```
int tolerance = 25;
        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
                v.performClick();
                int touchColor = getHotspotColor (R.id.imgMainAreas, evX, evY);
                if(x == 1){
                    if (ct.closeMatch (Color.BLUE, touchColor, tolerance)){
                        x = 2;
                        animStart();
                    }
                }
...
```

Anyway, the Class is marked as never used, the function within too. (closeMatch)
When I analyze the whole code of the App this happens too.
Maybe I forgive something?
I updated to latest Android Studio version.

Comment: can you post your whole main class? did you import exactly your class? you might have accidentally imported another class with same name

Comment: Sure I can, just done!

Comment: thanks. so does the code in the class doesn't run? or you are just annoyed that the android studio says it's not used when it in fact is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be two classes with the same name in different places and the Main uses the other one.

Comment: Really don't know why, how and when but I just discovered a Clone of the Class outside the project folder ^^ many thanks.